# Ao programar um microcontrolador ARM é possível alterar seu clock após a execução do SystemInit()?

Tags: c, arm

Retomei meus estudos sobre *ARM* este mês, e uma dúvida que já vem a tempo me incomodando e não consegui ainda por a prova em meu ambiente de testes é se posso mudar o `Clock("SystemCoreClock")` do meu microcontrolador mesmo depois de iniciado o `main()`, após portanto a execução da função `SystemInit()` padrão do CMSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Sim e foram feitos para isso como por exemplo em aplicações low power ou em sleep mode.
Atentar porém as mudança que irão afetar os periféricos e o programa que dependem deste tempo como PWMs, Timers ...

**Questão comum:**
[STFórum](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2Fcortex_mx_stm32%2FSysClock%20change%20during%20operation&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=1045)
[Kinetis](https://freescale.jiveon.com/thread/354774)